# jdbc driver not found when execute from exported Jar

Tags: java, exception, jdbc, jar, jaybird

I have a Java applet, it works correctly when executed from eclipe, but I want to export it to a Jar and use it. but when I do that, i get jdbc driver not found, it seems like when exporting, jaybird is not exported.

For exporting I use eclipse export and choose Java/JAR File, in build path i have jaybird mark to export.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure in Eclipse you use the option that involves packing libraries into the .jar I believe.

Comment: You can try adding your require Jar in a lib folder in the project.

Comment: @Austin that is using Runnable JAr File and I only have FBCommandLine launch configuration and it gives me an error

Comment: @J.Arenas This option? http://puu.sh/19Kpt

Comment: what about an installer? It will hold all the jars as one install pack. Anyway, for netbeans, I have used this one http://www.coderanch.com/t/419419/vc/there-way-netbeans-include-external. There are lot of suggestions, I have used the DOS SCRIPT

Comment: @Austin the problem with that is that automatically it selects FBCommandLine as Launch configuration and it gives me an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally get the answer, I had to sign the jaybird jar also because that jar was doing read/write operation in HDD

Answer (score 1):

Use [Fat Jar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) to build runnable JARs that contain all dependent libs

Comment: I tried it but when I try to execute I get subprogram not initialized and the browser dont show the applet

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely missing the files from the META-INF folder of the Jaybird jar file. These files are required for Jaybird to work. Another possibility is that you are missing one of the required dependencies of Jaybird (connector-api-1.5.jar, for Jaybird 2.2 or mini-j2ee.jar for earlier versions).

Even if you get this to work though, you will most likely experience an error later on, as Jaybird wasn't developed with support for applets in mind, see http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-254 and [NoClassDefFoundError with jdbc applet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10673119/466862)

BTW: Why don't you just use the jar as is. IMHO creating fat jars including all your dependencies is ugly and inflexible.

Comment: Please explain "use the jar as is", do you mean to add in the applet html tag archive=jaybird" ?

Comment: In general I would advice not to use applets. But if you really have to: you can specify additional archives in the `ARCHIVE` attribute of the applet tag. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/applet.html

Comment: I've tried that but some times I get subprogram not initialized, but that would be other problem, thanks!

Comment: I finally get the answer, I had to sign the jaybird jar also because that jar was doing read/write operation in HDD

Answer (score 0):

By using **Eclipse** you can simply solve the problem.
By going to `Eclipse -> File -> Export -> Runnable JAR file` and selecting `Extract required libraries into generated JAR` option, Eclipse will extract required libraries beside your project and creates the required **MANIFEST.MF** file for you and then will pack them all together in your JAR file.