# jar file not able to oracle driver

Tags: swing

hi I have created a project, containing swing classes. which is accessing oracle sql database. When running on eclipse my project is running fine. Butwhen I export it to a jar file, I get an error that it is not able to find the oracle driver class. There is no issue with the code as it is running properly in eclipse. Further I fave added the ojdbc jar to the lib folder as well as the classpath in java configuration. Also i have checked my exported jar file with 7 zip and it contains the ojdbc driver.

Comment: Where did you put the *JARs* and from where you are trying to execute the program? Can you provide more information please?

Comment: Are you getting a "ClassNotFoundException" for oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver? Can you show us some code about how you include the Oracle Driver?

Comment: Take a look at my answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654452/jdbc-driver-not-found-when-execute-from-exported-jar/54734239#54734239) question